# Is there a ready made function to transform a matrix into data frame of rows, columns and values?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

**I want to recast a matrix as a data frame with one column for rows, one for columns and one for the actual values stored in the matrix.**

Let us have an example matrix like that:

```
mat <- matrix(paste0(rep(1:5,3), rep(1:3,each=5)), 5, 3)
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "11" "12" "13"
# [2,] "21" "22" "23"
# [3,] "31" "32" "33"
# [4,] "41" "42" "43"
# [5,] "51" "52" "53"
```

With `as.vector()` and `rep()` I can construct the wanted result as such:

```
values  <- as.vector(mat)
rows    <- rep(seq_len(dim(mat)[1]), dim(mat)[2])
columns <- rep(seq_len(dim(mat)[2]), each=dim(mat)[1])
df      <- data.frame(rows, columns, values)
df
#    rows columns values
# 1     1       1     11
# 2     2       1     21
# 3     3       1     31
# 4     4       1     41
# 5     5       1     51
# 6     1       2     12
# 7     2       2     22
# 8     3       2     32
# 9     4       2     42
# 10    5       2     52
# 11    1       3     13
# 12    2       3     23
# 13    3       3     33
# 14    4       3     43
# 15    5       3     53
```

**Now, is there a *ready made* maybe more *performant* function in R or one of its package to do this?**

Comment: See, also, something like `as.data.frame.table(mat, base = list(as.character(seq_len(max(dim(mat))))))`

Comment: @alexis_laz, just edited my response to include as.data.frame.table() before I noticed your comment. Did not know about the 'base' argument- cool.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226862/rearrange-data-from-short-to-long-form-in-r/23227401#23227401

Comment: nope, the question you are referring to is about reshaping wide data format into long this here is about transforming matrix into df representation -- although a lot of the solutions to both problems might be interchangeable this is all but obvious from the problem definitions it only becomes apparent when thinking about it on very abstract level and with a much very big high lot of insight that cannot be attributed to us mere mortal folk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `reshape2` package:

```
melt(mat)
   Var1 Var2 value
1     1    1    11
2     2    1    21
3     3    1    31
4     4    1    41
5     5    1    51
6     1    2    12
7     2    2    22
8     3    2    32
9     4    2    42
10    5    2    52
11    1    3    13
12    2    3    23
13    3    3    33
14    4    3    43
15    5    3    53
```

A solution with base R:

```
as.data.frame.table(mat)
```

however, the above code does not produce the desired output because the matrix has no row/col names, and as.data.frame.table() puts letters instead. However, if the matrix has row/col names this works:

```
rownames(mat) = 1:5
colnames(mat) = 1:3
as.data.frame.table(mat)
```

That being said, `melt` is way faster with large matrices in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `which` and it's `arr.ind` argument

```
values <- as.vector(mat)
data.frame(which(mat == values, arr.ind = TRUE), values)
#    row col values
# 1    1   1     11
# 2    2   1     21
# 3    3   1     31
# 4    4   1     41
# 5    5   1     51
# 6    1   2     12
# 7    2   2     22
# 8    3   2     32
# 9    4   2     42
# 10   5   2     52
# 11   1   3     13
# 12   2   3     23
# 13   3   3     33
# 14   4   3     43
# 15   5   3     53
```

Comment: Perhaps, you could avoid creating a logical vetor and calling `which` by using `arrayInd` directly; something like `data.frame(arrayInd(seq_along(mat), dim(mat)), values)`

Comment: @alexis_laz, could be, but it will call `mat` twice instead of once. It will also call `seq_along` and `dim`. Not sure how this is an improvement

Comment: Hm, I'm only referring to a possible speed gain. `seq_along` loops once and just saves its "i" in an integer vector while `which(x == y)` loops twice to create a logical and an integer vector. `dim` just gets an attribute.

Comment: @alexis_laz, I see what you mean. I didn't look in the source code of `which` before

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
data.frame(Var1=c(row(mat)), Var2=c(col(mat)), value=c(mat))
```

Answer (score 1):

`expand.grid` can produce the row and column combinations efficiently, and then you can `cbind` the data:

```
cbind(expand.grid(rows=seq(nrow(mat)),columns=seq(ncol(mat))),values=c(mat))
   rows columns values
1     1       1     11
2     2       1     21
3     3       1     31
4     4       1     41
5     5       1     51
6     1       2     12
7     2       2     22
8     3       2     32
9     4       2     42
10    5       2     52
11    1       3     13
12    2       3     23
13    3       3     33
14    4       3     43
15    5       3     53
```

Answer (score -1):

The ready-made function in the base of R is `as.data.frame.table`:

```
as.data.frame.table(mat)
##    Var1 Var2 Freq
## 1     A    A   11
## 2     B    A   21
## 3     C    A   31
## etc.
```

It uses the row and column names of `mat` as values in the first two output columns and if there are none it defaults to upper case letters, as seen above.

If you don't like letters, specify the `dimnames`, e.g. try this which specifies numbers rather than letters and specifies `rows`, `columns` and `value` as the column names:

```
dimnames(mat) <- list(rows = 1:nrow(mat), columns = 1:ncol(mat))
as.data.frame.table(mat, responseNAme = "value")
##    rows columns value
## 1     1       1    11
## 2     2       1    21
## 3     3       1    31
## etc.
```

or for a non-destructive version using numbers but not changing the column names:

```
as.data.frame.table(mat, base = list(paste(1:nrow(mat)), paste(1:ncol(mat))))
##    Var1 Var2 Freq
## 1     1    1   11
## 2     2    1   21
## 3     3    1   31
## etc.
```